# Python. Проблема с функцией

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу код под поиск пути в графе. С функцией самой помогли,вроде. Но возникает ошибка,получаемая на скрине. Как от нее избавиться?

Или я неверно склеил основу с функцией? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам код:

```
 elif r == 2:
    print("Введите кол-во точек графа: ")   
    n = int(input())
    print("Заполните матрицу смежности:")
    matrix=[]
    matrix = [[int(input())
       for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
    print(matrix)

graph={i:set()for i in range(n)}
 for i in range(n):
     for j in range(n):
      if 1==matrix[i][j]:
        graph[i].add(j)
        graph[j].add(i)
print(graph)

def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not start in graph.keys():
        return None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath: return newpath
    return None

print(find_path(graf,0,3,path=[]))
```

Comment: А каковы входные данные?

Comment: Входные данные к чему именно?

Comment: Видимо у вас есть функция `graph`

Comment: Ошибка синтаксическая в поле, поменяй имя на ```graph```:
```graf={i:set()for i in range(n)}```

Comment: Вопрос был на самом деле глупый,а я невнимательный)
Спасибо за помощь.